# Android AsyncTask - how to show data from url

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've read a lot about this subject but I'm still not getting the result I want.
I have an URL (http://e085d133.ngrok.io/android_merenja) that I need to get the data from and show it on the android screen.
I've followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EThkglxLxSM , but I just need to show data, not calculate.

I've created a onPreExecute, onPostExecute and a doInBackground where it should be getting the data. **But I have an error: com.example.ivanp.msnis.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class**

I need to get the data from the url and strore it in a variable.
Here is my code:

```
package com.example.ivanp.msnis;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TvrdjavaFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btnIdinaperiod;
    TextView pokaziServer;
    String rezultat = "";
    String strURL = "http://e085d133.ngrok.io/android_merenja";

    public TvrdjavaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tvrdjava, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        pokaziServer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.testServer);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(pokaziServer.getText().toString());

        new NabaviServer().execute();

        });

        return view;
    }

    public class NabaviServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //super.onPostExecute(s);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Izlazak je: " + rezultat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try{
                URL url = new URL(strURL);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.connect();

                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); //??s

                String value = bf.readLine();
                System.out.println("test " + value);
                rezultat = value;

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Izlazak je: " + rezultat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

to this

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Izlazak je: " + rezultat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

because your code present in `TvrdjavaFragment` and inside this fragment you cannot use MainActivity.this for context instead you can use `getActivity()` to get the activity context inside the fragment.

Well its better to check the output by printing response in the Logs provided by android, like you may use `Log.d("Izlazak je:",rezultat);` and you may read more about logs here [Logs in android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: @lkePr try my answer

Comment: I get an error at         
pokaziServer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.testServer); int i = Integer.parseInt(pokaziServer.getText().toString()); FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.ivanp.msnis, PID: 28046
                                                   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "testServer"

Comment: make sure the id of textview is testServer in xml and also post your xml if this error is not resolved another thing is that you are parsing the data of textview in Integer are you sure its value is purely Integer or not

Comment: Invalid int: "testServer" means you have a value "testServer" which is string and you can't parse it to the Integer

Comment: I think this is the problem: pokaziServer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.testServer); int i = Integer.parseInt(pokaziServer.getText().toString()); How can I get i to be a string, to parse a string to pokaziServer ??

Comment: There is no problem in the code except you enter string and parse to int. getText() returns object so it is required to parse it to string then to int

Answer (score 1):

`Toast.makeText` use the object `MainActivity.this`, but this is in your Fragment class. Normally, `XXX.this` is only used in class XXX to refer the class XXX instance itself.

### option 1

You can call `getActivity()` to get the reference of the Activity which the fragment attached.

But be careful, according to the life cycle of Fragment `getActivity()` only return valid value between `Fragment.onAttach` and `Fragment.onDetach`. If `onPostExecute` is executed before `onAttach` or after `onDetach`, `getActivity()` will return null.

So check the return value of `getActivity()` before you use it. Otherwise it will cause crash.

### option 2

You can also use Application context for Toast. The following code create your own Application class, then you can use `MyApplication.getInstance()` as context everywhere in your code. Like this `Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getInstance(), ...).show()`. Remember to call `show()` after `makeText`, your code miss it.

public class MyApplication extends Application {

```
private static MyApplication instance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
}

public static MyApplication getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
```

}

Comment: I think it is required to attach the MyApplication class in the manifest

Answer (score 0):

Your toast is using an unknown context 
Please change it to the application context or the local context

```
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Izlazak je: " + rezultat,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

Comment: you can't get getApplicationContext() inside the fragment without using getActivity()